# Using "du" and "de" in a phrase: "champion du monde de ..."

Tags: grammaire, articles

I have stumbled across a phrase:
"champion du monde de ..."
I am a bit confused about the choice of articles.

The first, I suppose, means "champion of the world ..." and since in French we need articles almost everywhere, I am fine with it. But then following the same logic I would expect "du" instead of "de" for the second part like in "champion du monde du basket". Why do we actually need to skip a definite article here and simply put "de"?

Thank you!

Comment: "in French we need articles almost everywhere". Well there are some instances where English put an article and French does not : "je suis photographe" vs "I'm **a** photographer"

Answer (score 5):

In "champion du monde de basket", "Le monde" is definite (du = de le) whereas "basket" is a not an explicit thing but a general concept, a domain and is therefore indefinite.

The same rule applies frequently. For instance you would say "diplôme d'ingénieur" (engineering degree) and not "diplôme de l'ingénieur".

Comment: Thank you for the answer! May I also ask please why it is correct to say "faire du basket" even though "basket" here is also a general concept (correct me please if I am wrong). I know that some verbs may require "de" but I am not sure that verbs ca require "du".

Comment: I think this case is different. In the first case, "De" prefixes the domain (you can ask "De quoi est-il champion du Monde?). In the second case, "Faire de" is a specific form or the "Faire" verb which means to practice or sport or activity.

Comment: Monde isn't a "nom propre" in this expression so I believe you should use *champion du **m**onde*. On the other hand, *Le Monde* is a newspaper...

Comment: @jlliagre Thanks, fixed